# Server File Configuration: Using .htaccess to redirect to a script but pass CGI arguments aswell

Tags: php, python, .htaccess, webserver

I have an idea that will allow a Web Forums Content/Threads to be better indexed by search engines but avoid taking up too much unnecessary space on the web server.

My idea is not unique(I think StackOverflow uses it) but **I am having difficulty working out how I am going to achieve redirecting through .htaccess commands or main server configuration files.**

*For a web forum website; when a new thread is created:*

- I store the thread HTML in an SQL database(rather than creating a HTML file which I think will take up more server space - is that correct?).
- I create a directory on the server where the directory's name is the threads name(this will allow for easier indexing from google & other search engines wont it? Because the url is more descriptive?). So www.myForum.com/posts/unique_thread_name/. I think this is how StackOverflow does this, if you look at the url of my question its a directory.
- The new directory(thread directory) will be empty except for a .htaccess file which will redirect to a script www.myForum.com/cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py. This script will grab the thread's HTML from the database when accessed & display that thread.
- So when someone accesses www.myForum.com/posts/unique_thread_name/, the .htaccess file will redirect to  www.myForum.com/cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py?thread=unique_thread_name. Notice the arguments, is it possible for a .htaccess file to redirect to a script but pass arguments aswell?

**My Questions:**

- The apache website says you should never use .htaccess files *"In general, you should never use .htaccess files unless you don't have access to the main server configuration file."*. If I am using a webhost like GoDaddy do I have access to this file or is this server config file only for VPS?
- Is it better to do this with the Server Config file instead?
- Is there a way easier way of doing this? **The whole idea is to store Forum Threads that take up as little space as possible but are still easy for search engines to index(thus the unique directories created).**
- Do I NOT need to create a .htaccess file in each post directory? Can I just write in my main .htaccess file that any request to a file/folder in posts should redirect to www.myForum.com/cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py?thread=the directory they accessed?

Maybe the code would look something like this?

```
Redirect /posts/* www.myForum.com/cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py?thread="HOW DO I SPECIFY THE FOLDER?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I am using a webhost like GoDaddy do I have access to this file or is this server config file only for VPS?

Godaddy shared hosting only allows .htaccess use.

> Is it better to do this with the Server Config file instead?

Its better performing if you have access to Server Config, but shared hosting like Godaddy does not allow it.

> Do I NOT need to create a .htaccess file in each post directory? Can I just write in my main .htaccess file that any request to a file/folder in posts should redirect to www.myForum.com/cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py?thread=the directory they accessed?

You can do it with a single .htaccess in the root dir of your site with contents as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^posts/(.+)/$ /cgi-bin/loadWebpage.py?thread=$1 [NC,L]
```